# Showing that a function from a topology to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

I am trying to prove the following:

Prove that $f(X,\mathcal{T})\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f^{-1}((-\infty,a))$ and $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ are in $\mathcal{T}$

but I am struggling. I start by supposing that $f$ is continuous, and then picking an open set $U\in \mathbb{R}$ and then from continuity we must have that $f^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal{T}$, but then from here I cannot see how this helps me say that $f^{-1}((-\infty,a))$ and $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ are in $\mathcal{T}$. Is it simply a matter of picking $U=(-\infty,a)$ and then $U=(a,\infty)$?

Going back the other way, I am even more stumped! Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is that simple. – For the other direction, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2493557/42969.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\{x:f(x) > a\}$ and $\{x:f(x) < a\}$ are open$\forall~a\in\mathbb{R}$ then f is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493557/if-xfx-a-and-xfx-a-are-open-foralla-in-mathbbr-then-f)